# Refresh na página ao dar resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho minha função para resize,

```
    function resizeGrid() {
      $(".divGrid").css("height", ($(document).height() - 325) + "px");
    }
    $(resizeGrid);
```

Ela funciona como eu gostaria, mas ao testar no navegador, sempre tenho que dar f5 para que ela funcione,como faço para que quando ele solte o botão do mouse, após o resize, chame essa função?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras possíveis. Estas são algumas:

**Via DOM**

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    resizeGrid();
};
```

**Via Event Listener**

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
    resizeGrid();
});
```

**Via jQuery**

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeGrid();
});
```

Comment: OnoSendai, ele até chama a função, mas para ver visualmente, tenho que dar f5

Comment: @Rod Você teria um exemplo reproduzindo este comportamento?

Comment: coloquei um  location reload também no resize, aí funciona, não sei se é uma boa...